# Detect loops in geometry

Tags: vba, geometry

I'm looking for a way to detect loops in geometry using VBA (not excel). I start with a geometric shape, containing an outer profile. It may also contain inner profiles and open or closed loops.

The image below is a simplified example of one such  . The black lines are the geometry, and each line has start and end points with X & Y Coordinates.

[image: Example profile with lines and points]

Its easy enough to detect whether lines are joined to other lines (for example, I can identify that the vertical line at the top is not connected to the rest of the lines).

The aim is to identify 4 closed loops and 1 open loop in this image.
The closed loops should be:

1. The outer profile.
2. The top inner profile.
3. The bottom inner profile.
4. The circle.

And the open loop should be the vertical line at the top.

Note that the first 3 profiles share geometry - this is acceptable.

I found a possible solution some time back when looking for a solution to a 3D problem, whereby you take any point on the surface of the object and cast a ray in the two directions normal to the surface. If the ray passes through 0 (not including itself) or an even number of surfaces (including itself), then it's an outer profile. If it passes through an odd number of surfaces (including itself), then it's an internal profile.
However, in this case, the inclusion of open internal loops messes that up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking this in relation to Solidwork and its incapability to identify what is wrong in your Sketch ;-)

Comment: haha - No, this is for Inventor for a custom project. Asked generally, because I believe the answer will be a general form.